# Custom Control chart on panel in c#

Tags: c#, charts, controls, mousewheel

how to create a custom control chart in c# using vs2015. i want it to create on panel but need it start from bottom not start form up. thanks in advance.

Comment: What chart library are you using? What language is this?

Comment: This might be helpful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876818/make-datavisualization-chart-object-zoom-and-scrollable-by-dragging-the-scroll-b