# How to make ASPX Chart zoomable

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to make my `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` ASPX chart zoomable like in C#.

In C# I used the `this.Diagramm.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Diagramm_MouseWheel)` and `Diagramm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` but this is not working for ASPX.

Also tried it with `IsUserEnabled` but it's not available. Also looked around like [enable-scrolling-on-the-microsoft-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212914/enable-scrolling-on-the-microsoft-chart-control-for-windows-forms/1213565#1213565) but I have not those settings.

So how can I zoom in and out on a ASPX chart? Thanks!

Or are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Found http://dygraphs.com